# prevent a client from accessing shared folder NFS (RED HAT)

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, centos, nfs

I want to share a folder with all the network's clients except only one
this is my current `/etc/exports` file :

```
     /opt/resources     *(rw,async)
```

what should I add to prevent the client `192.168.1.24` without the need to mention all other authorized clients adresses?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ would be more appropriate places to ask this as it is not about programming.

Comment: thanks retired ninga, it's done :)